# jcarousel with external controls.... thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, jcarousel

I want the external controls (below) to be images. But nothing except numbers (in the below order) seems to work.

--

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>jCarousel Examples</title>
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--
  jQuery library
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<!--
  jCarousel library
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<!--
  jCarousel skin stylesheet
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../skins/tango/skin.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
{
    // Disable autoscrolling if the user clicks the prev or next button.
    carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 2,
        wrap: 'last',
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
  <h1>jCarousel</h1>
  <h2>Riding carousels with jQuery</h2>

  <h3>Carousel with autoscrolling</h3>
  <p>
    Autoscrolling is enabled and the interval is set to <code>2</code> seconds.
    Autoscrolling pauses when the user moves the cursor over the images and stops
    when the user clicks the next or prev button. <code>wrap</code> is set to
    <code>&quot;last&quot;</code>.
  </p>

  <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>

    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.benjamingaw.com/website/blog/jcarousel-external-linking/

Answer (score 1):

The above answer helped me solve a similar issue where I needed the external control start number to be '0' rather than '1'.  The quoted code on the page has a syntax error in that it doesn't close the function.  Should be:

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
    jQuery('.jcarousel-control a').bind('click', function() {
        var index = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
        carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(index[1]));
        //carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(jQuery(this).text()));
        $(".jcarousel-control a").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active");
        return false;
    });
    jQuery('.jcarousel-scroll select').bind('change', function() {
        carousel.options.scroll = jQuery.jcarousel.intval(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
        return false;
    }); // example ends here
}; // should end here
```